# autofs and NFS failover - can autofs remount?

Tags: automount, autofs

I have this scenario:

- 2 NFS servers with /usr/share/man as exports (just as example, it can be anything), let say server A and server B (not replicas, just 2 independent servers on the same subnet sharing the same things)
- both NFS servers are up and healthy
- user is initiating mount from client by executing ls /mnt/usr/man (as example); timeout in auto.master is 2 minutes, fstype=nfs, options=ro,soft
- automount is successful, server A was chosen by autofs, and user can see listed man pages
- after 1m 10sec server (NFS) A goes down
- at 1m 20 sec user executes ls /mnt/usr/man again

What is happening is that it is locked - mount stays on server A and no user can go into /mnt/usr/man (nor lsof is working)

After waiting some minutes (ca 10 minutes)

`ls: cannot open directory /mnt/usr/man: Input/output error`

My question is: should autofs manage this scenario and automatically remount to server B? (even if mount timeout has not finished yet?)

I have read many articles and it looks like my scenario is not "autofs"'es duty (If I want something like this it should be done another way).

But I want to be sure 100% whether autofs should handle this situation itself or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty late to the party, but was the nfs-server service started on server B? I just ran into these exact symptoms, and that was the solution. Try running `service nfs-server start` on server B.